# Backward Search through NSData doesn't work, still reads from the front

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I have the following problem in objective C: In a larger context I would like to search in a String for a substring and get the position, where the first such substring is located. I also want the search to start from the back.  so for example:
calling the desired function on "K123K" with searching "K" should result in 3, because I start from the back.

In My Code it's more efficient to search through a NSData object, because that is what I read in. So I tried a little test code out to see if my proposed method works:

```
    NSString *testString = @"01K234567K";
    NSData *testData = [testString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *testLetter = @"K";
    NSData *kData = [testLetter dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSRange whereisK = [testData rangeOfData:kData options:NSBackwardsSearch      range:NSMakeRange(0, [testData length])];
    NSLog(@"loc: %d, len: %d",whereisK.location,whereisK.length);
```

The result is against my expectations, it seems like rangeOfData starts searching still from the front:

```
    loc: 2, len: 1
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. It seems like NSBackwardsSearch is not doing its job as an option! I happy for any help or suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct value for the option is `NSDataSearchBackwards`. The option you are using is used for NSString searches. You can read about it the [NSData documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-SW18).